# Displaying local times in GWT

Tags: java, date, datetime, gwt

I have an app where I need to display events in local time, *not* in the user's time zone, but in the time zone of where the event is taking place. I am getting the time in ISO-8601 format, including the time zone offset. The time zone is not constant, each event I'm displaying can have a different one (they represent flight departure and arrival times).

For example, I have "2014-02-05T09:00-08:00" and I want to display this as "9:00am".

My first, naive code looked like this:

```
private static final DateTimeFormat ISO_TIME_FORMAT =
    DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZZZ");
private static final DateTimeFormat TIME_OF_DAY_FORMAT =
    DateTimeFormat.getFormat(PredefinedFormat.HOUR_MINUTE);

public static String formatTimeOfDay(String iso8601Time) {
  return TIME_OF_DAY_FORMAT.format(QPX_TIME_FORMAT.parse(iso8601Time));
}
```

But this displays the time in the *user's* timezone, in my case "6:00am", since I'm in US ET.

Looking at the GWT reference, it looks like I need to get hold of the right TimeZone based on the ISO-8601 date, but I'm not clear on how to do this. I tried

```
public static String formatTimeOfDay(String isoTime) {
  Date date = QPX_TIME_FORMAT.parse(isoTime);
  String tzoneStr = qpxTime.substring(16);
  TimeZone tzone = TimeZone.createTimeZone(tzoneStr);
  return TIME_OF_DAY_FORMAT.format(date, tzone);
}
```

But I get an "Error parsing JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected number -05:00" exception. It seems like I should be able to parse both the Date and the TimeZone from the  input string, since it has all that information encoded in it.

At this point, it seems like the easiest thing would be just to extract the time-of-day directly from the input time, via isoTime.substring(11, 16). That means that I would have to write a custom parser to convert from 24-hour to am/pm formats, but that might be easiest.

Any alternative suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In GWT 2.5.1 TimeZone.createTimeZone gets a JSON version of [TimeZoneInfo](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/TimeZoneInfo.java.html) (this JSON version can be found in [TimeZoneConstants.properties](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/constants/TimeZoneConstants.properties)). In order to create that JSON version from the "-08:00" zone offset you have to parse it yourself. But even with the proper TimeZone it still doesn't work for me:

```
DateTimeFormat ISO_TIME_FORMAT = DateTimeFormat.getFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZZZ");
DateTimeFormat TIME_OF_DAY_FORMAT = DateTimeFormat.getFormat (PredefinedFormat.HOUR_MINUTE);
String qpxTime = "2014-02-05T09:00-08:00";
RootPanel.get().add (new Label ("dts: " + qpxTime));
Date dt = ISO_TIME_FORMAT.parse (qpxTime);
RootPanel.get().add (new Label ("dt: " + dt.toString()));
String tzs = qpxTime.substring (16);
RootPanel.get().add (new Label ("tzs: " + tzs));
int tzh = Integer.parseInt (qpxTime.substring (16, qpxTime.indexOf (':', 16)));
RootPanel.get().add (new Label ("tzh: " + tzh));
// cf. http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/TimeZoneInfo.java.html
// cf. http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/constants/TimeZoneConstants.properties
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.createTimeZone ("{\"id\": \"fromOffset\", \"std_offset\": " + (tzh * 60) + ", \"transitions\": [], \"names\": \"\"}");
RootPanel.get().add (new Label ("tz: " + tz));
RootPanel.get().add (new Label ("format plain: " + TIME_OF_DAY_FORMAT.format (dt)));  // 9:00 AM
// cf. http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/i18n/shared/DateTimeFormat.java
RootPanel.get().add (new Label ("format tz: " + TIME_OF_DAY_FORMAT.format (dt, tz)));  // 9:00 AM
RootPanel.get().add (new Label ("tz offset: " + tz.getStandardOffset()));  // 480
RootPanel.get().add (new Label ("format custom: " + TIME_OF_DAY_FORMAT.format (new Date (dt.getTime() + 60L * 60L * 1000L * tzh))));  // 1:00 PM
```

If all your times contain the zone offset then you can apply it to the time manually. But if you want to parse the standard zone names too then it seems to me that you have either to parse the [TimeZoneConstants.properties](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/constants/TimeZoneConstants.properties) on the client or offload the time conversions to the server.